# concat two integers and result as string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In table, 2 fields ID as int and Number as small int and i want to concatenate the two fields and display as string

```
eg: ID = 101 and Number = 9 
output : 101.9
```

Dot to be added in between ID and Number?
How to query in SQL?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can [CAST](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) your integer field to varchar and then concatenate them as you want.

```
DECLARE @ID INT 
DECLARE @Number INT 

SET @ID = 101 
SET @Number = 9  

SELECT CAST(@ID AS VARCHAR(10) ) +'.'+ CAST(@Number AS VARCHAR(10) )
```

Answer (score 15):

In SQL 2012 (and later) I now find this easier using CONCAT ([better performance](https://raresql.com/2013/03/12/sql-server-string-concatenation-faster-method/) too)

```
SELECT CONCAT(@ID, '.', @Number)
```

any NULL elements are converted to empty-strings preventing NULL propagation, which saves having to do the even more complex:

```
SELECT ISNULL(CAST(@ID AS VARCHAR(10) ), '') +'.'+ ISNULL(CAST(@Number AS VARCHAR(10) ) , '')
```