# Sql concatenate integer columns to string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two int columns in my table.

I want to concatenate them like a string

for example : `A = 12345 , B = 2`

I want to return `123452`.

How can I do that ?

Comment: But why do you want to do that?!? First cast to char, then concat.

Comment: or use `concat`. [`SELECT CONCAT(12345,2)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19067649/concat-two-integers-and-result-as-string-in-sql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like this:

```
select CAST(A as varchar(10)) + CAST(B as varchar(10))
```

**[SQL DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/1305)**

Comment: I did this, but it make my query slow, do u have a quicker query to do that?

Comment: @BrMe:- I think you are running a different query then the one which I posted. What is the query which you are trying and which is taking time? Also the above query is quick enough, I dont think that you can achieve this any more faster than this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like below

```
SELECT NUMBER_COL1,
       NUMBER_COL2,
       CAST(NUMBER_COL1 AS VARCHAR(10)) + CAST(NUMBER_COL1 AS VARCHAR(10)) JOINED_NUM
  FROM TABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code:

```
declare @a int
declare @b int

select @a='12345'
select @b='2'

select cast(@a as char(10))+cast(@b as char(10)) as Concatenation
```

Answer (score 0):

But you can use math functions too. For example, in ORACLE SQL:

```
SELECT A * Power( 10, Length(B) ) + B FROM DUAL;
```